# File-sharing on cloud or on premises?

Tags: cloud, office365, file-sharing

What would be the best solution in this scenario.

We have 20 computer each with 128 SSD disk space.
We all need access to a shared folder with a total of 100gb of files.

We are using "own-cloud" storage as today with synchronization therefore all computers are running out of space.
Would it be a good idea to use office 365 with share point and one drive "on demand", so the files does not take space on our local disk?

Or a server on premises but then need to build a file server with shared folder and handle the access to user from inside and outside the network.

Another idea would be to have one server in the cloud running 20 copy of virtual windows 10 desktop with citrix. Can be also used as a file server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using sharepoint and onedrive on demand (so files are not downloaded on local pc.)